# How do I reference a DLL in a .net script without Visual Studio

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-manipulation

How do I reference a DLL in a C# script? I'm not using Visual Studio, I'm just using NPP with a C# plugin to write a quick one file script. That script needs to reference a third party DLL. Is there a code snippet that I can include to accomplish this?

The DLL I want to reference is for iTextSharp

Comment: You say you're using "a C# plugin" - *which* C# plugin? That's what will determine what you need to do...

Comment: The NPP plugin is calle CS-Script I don't think it can manage DLLs though.

Comment: @Frantumn I removed my answer because it seems like some people won't understand it, but it's not true it should be a comment, because I pointed out that C# isn't a scripting language and I provided you a scripting alternative, if you were looking to script using .NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now we know the plugin you're using, it's easy. Just read the [documentation on "Using .NET assemblies"](http://www.csscript.net/help/Using_.NET_assemblies.html). In particular, it sounds like you want:

```
//css_reference iTextSharp.dll;
```

That's assuming the library is one of the locations CSScript can find automatically - read the linked documentation for more information and options.

Comment: Thank you! That appears to build.

Comment: @JonSkeet I didn't know about CS Script. It seems like a future NodeJS but on top of .NET :O

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: I didn't know about CS Script, but I know a bit about ScriptCS. Yes, those are two different projects :(

Comment: @JonSkeet Did you know I misspelled ScriptCS and I pointed you to an existing project? hahaha Well, now we both know about a new project!

Answer (score 0):

You can load the assembly dynamically from a file

```
Assembly.LoadFrom("iTextSharp.dll");
```

Comment: Loading an assembly != compiler reference

Comment: I agree. But Loading the assembly does the jobs in this case

Comment: I just stumbled upon [DllImport("iTextSharp.dll")] which I place just insude the class brackets. Does this sound like something I should use instead?

Comment: @Frantumn: No. That's for P/Invoke - calling native methods, basically. You need to give us more information about the NPP plugin.